# QToolButton clicked signal is only called once

Tags: python, pyqt, qtoolbutton

I have attached a QMenu to the QToolButton in which the Menu is not reflecting correctly.

I am populating my QMenu from reading a `.txt` file. The menu is showing the correct items on the first run, but if I made changes in the .txt file and re-clicked on the button, the QMenu is still showing the item on the first run.

Adding on, it seems that the `clicked` signal is only being called once?

```
class MyWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        vlay.addStretch()

        self.add_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.tab_bar = QtGui.QTabBar(self)
        self.add_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('add.png'))
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.set_menu)

        #self.add_button.setMenu(self.set_menu())
        #self.add_button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.tab_bar.setTabButton(
            0,
            QtGui.QTabBar.ButtonPosition.RightSide,
            self.add_button
        )
        hlay.addWidget(self.add_button)
        hlay.addWidget(self.tab_bar)

    def set_menu(self):
        with open('/Desktop/item_file.txt') as f:
            menu_options = f.read().splitlines()
            print menu_options

        qmenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.add_button)
        for opt in menu_options:
            qmenu.addAction(opt, partial(self.set_new_tab, opt))

        self.add_button.setMenu(qmenu)
        self.add_button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

    def set_new_tab(self, opt):
        self.tab_bar.addTab(opt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Menu is established in the `QPushButton`, the `mousePressEvent` event no longer reaches the `QPushButton` but is intercepted by the `QMenu` so the clicked signal is not emited.

One solution is to set a QMenu by default and use the `aboutToShow` signal to call set_menu that will add the `QAction`s.

On the other hand they are the same because clicked is not issued and therefore set_menu is not called, and even if you call set_menu as I have established it is better to reuse than create so in this case I eliminate the previous QActions with clear method.

```
from functools import partial
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        vlay.addStretch()

        self.add_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.tab_bar = QtGui.QTabBar(self)
        self.add_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('add.png'))

        self.qmenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.add_button)
        self.add_button.setMenu(self.qmenu)
        self.add_button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.qmenu.aboutToShow.connect(self.set_menu)

        self.tab_bar.setTabButton(
            0,
            QtGui.QTabBar.ButtonPosition.RightSide,
            self.add_button
        )
        hlay.addWidget(self.add_button)
        hlay.addWidget(self.tab_bar)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def set_menu(self):
        with open('/Desktop/item_file.txt') as f:
            menu_options = f.read().splitlines()
            self.qmenu.clear()
            for opt in menu_options:
                self.qmenu.addAction(opt, partial(self.set_new_tab, opt))

    def set_new_tab(self, opt):
        self.tab_bar.addTab(opt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I kindly ask in what instances do I need to use `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()`? I have seeing them in some examples but do not really know when to use them... Additionally, could I also kindly ask if there is a command that allows me to query for all the items within the `qmenu`?